# Save images in Azure SQL Database through android app

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-sql-database

I have to store images from android app in Azure SQL database, I have tried to search on stack-overflow and googled it on many other sites , but I couldn't find an appropriate answer. I have seen some way on some sites but It was in C#, but I am a java guy. I tried it to find a way on Azure portal, where I just found a Easy Table function through which I can just make a table with no data type to save image.

Plase suggest me a way.
My task is that I have to save one image and 2-3 text strings through android app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Per my experience, normally saving images in Azure SQL Database is not a good idea. On Azure, the best practice is creating an Azure Mobile App instance to handle the request to save images using Azure Blob Storage. But by now, the Azure Mobile App only supports C# & NodeJS, and I think NodeJS is easy for you, which is `express.js` on Azure. Please see the tutorial below to know them.

1. [How to use the Azure Mobile Apps Node.js SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk)
2. [How to use Blob storage from Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage)

Or you can directly use Azure Blob Storage in Android, that you can refer to the offical documents & samples.

1. Sample: [Azure Storage Service - Photo Uploader Sample for Android](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/storage-blob-android-photo-uploader/)
2. Library: [Azure Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android)
3. Tutorial: [How to use Blob storage from Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage)

However, to save images in Azure SQL Database via easy table is a required needs. My suggestion is as below.

1. Encode image within Base64 to a string
2. Split the Base64 string to a string array, and make sure the length of the array string item is less than the length of the defined character column.
3. Save the index of the above array as a table column to easy table, then you can recover the Base64 string of image via concat the string array by the index.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for this info but, Is there any update on Mobile Apps for Android - files storage? Should I combine "Azure Mobile Apps" with "Azure Storage" if I want to save both data and files? I am facing a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178505/image-files-sync-in-azure-mobile-apps-for-android/46192521#46192521