# Image files sync in Azure Mobile Apps for Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

Sorry if this question does not contain any code. I am building an Android app using Azure Mobile Apps. I am successfully following the sample with 
[the TodoList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data) .
The sample describes the case for data sync, but what if I want to add support for images sync? Do I have to save the image files as blob inside the database? Do I treat files as any other record in the db, or is there a better way? Do I have to use a service other than "Mobile Apps"?

I've also read the following instructions about image sync, but they don't seem to target Android:

[Azure Mobile Apps - structured data sync with files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/)

Answer (score 0):

> I've also read the following instructions about image sync, but they don't seem to target Android:

The assemblies used for file sync is a prerelease version. I suggest you implement the file sync feature for your Android device by yourself currently. To implement the sync feature, I suggest you create a table to store the file log. The table definition should be like this.

```
+-------------------+
|    Column Name    |
+-------------------+
| File name         |
| Operation type    |
| Modified date     |
+-------------------+
```

After created or deleted the file on your device, we need to add a log record to the file log table. To sync the files, we need to compare the differences between local data and remote data on this table to sync the files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and directions. It seems that it can be done but I really want to avoid implementing this by myself. Do you know if I can combine any other azure service with Mobile Apps so I can have both data and  files sync? So the Mobile Apps is not meant for files? I see many available services here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/?v=16.50

Comment: Azure Storage is used to store data on cloud side. To sync files between client and server side, we need to wrote logic to compare the data between client and server side.

Comment: thank you. Do you know if I can combine Mobile Apps with Azure Storage? I found this tutorial for the older Mobile Services and I am about to try to apply with modifications for Mobile Apps: http://chrisrisner.com/Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage

Comment: Yes, you can. It is a good idea to store file using Azure Blob Storage.